# Iterate array in Object from Class using fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, fetch

I've a class with viewData() method that pull the data from the DB table.
I want to return the data result array in Class and iterate the array in Object
I'm able to make it work with fetchAll() but couldn't figure it out how to return the result with fetch() using while loop.

```
<?php
   class CrudClass{

        private $db;        
        function __construct($DB_con){
            $this->db = $DB_con;
        }

        /* DATA VIEW METHOD */     
        public function viewData(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();

            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                return $row; // it doesn't work         
            }           

            // below code is working
            /*if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
             }*/

        }           
    }

    // instantiate an Object
    $obj = new CrudClass($DB_con);
    $rows = $obj->viewData();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
     echo $row['first_name']. " ". $row['last_name'] ."<br>";
    }
?>
```

The reason I want to do that way, because I don't want to pull the data at one go with fetchAll. Instead want to loop through each row at a time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should return array.

```
$result = []; // initiate the array
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
    return $result[] = $row; // put each row in the result array
} 

return $result; // return the result array
```

Now the whole method will look something like below

```
/* DATA VIEW METHOD */     
public function viewData() {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = []; // initiate the array
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
        return $result[] = $row; // put each row in the result array
    } 

    return $result; // return the result array
}
```

This way you are assured that even if there is no result set, only array will get returned.

If above doesn't work. Try following two solutions.

1.Test explicitly for false.

```
while(($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) !== false) {
    return $result[] = $row; // put each row in the result array
}
```

2.Use foreach

```
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
     return $result[] = $row; // put each row in the result array
}
```

Comment: But it still returning the one result when I use it in Object. How can I loop it in the object so I can get all the query result. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer with two more solutions. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to return something you can use in a `foreach` without having to preload all the results (i.e. using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`) and without returning the `PDOStatement` itself -- if that's what you are trying to do.

Because `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` you you can construct an `IteratorIterator` from the `PDOStatement` and return that.

```
class CrudClass
{
    public function viewData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        return new \IteratorIterator($stmt);
    }
}

// instantiate an Object
$obj = new CrudClass($DB_con);
$rows = $obj->viewData();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['first_name']. " ". $row['last_name'] ."<br>";
}
```

Note that if you were try and foreach over `$rows` more than once, it will error because because the results of a PDOStatement cannot be rewound.